EFCORE8 Postgresql can't be translated when use all with contains in LINQ
I have a model called MapInfo which has MapTags field.
I want to bring in a List to find if there are matching items in the database, like the following SQL syntax.
select * from "MapInfo"
where "MapInfo"."MapTags" @> ARRAY[0,1000];

I'd also like to do the same thing using LINQ.
But when I use LINQ to search for data, I get an error message.
Query Code
IQueryable<MapInfo> query = dbContext.MapInfo.AsNoTracking();

// Method 1
query = query.Where(map => map.MapTags != null && param.MapTags.All(tag => map.MapTags.Contains(tag)));
// Method 2
query = query.Where(map => param.MapTags.All(tag => map.MapTags.Any(t => t == tag)));
// Method 3
query = query.Where(map => map.MapTags != null);
foreach (var tag in param.MapTags)
{
    query = query.Where(map => map.MapTags.Any(v => v == tag));
}
// Method 4
query = query.Where(map => map.MapTags != null);
foreach (var tag in param.MapTags)
{
    query = query.Where(map => map.MapTags.Contains(tag));
}

Error message
 System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression '__param_MapTags_0
    .All(e => StructuralTypeShaperExpression: 
        MapInfo
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
        IsNullable: False
    .MapTags
        .Contains(e))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains' failed.

Data Model
// setting in DbContext
modelBuilder.Entity<MapInfo>().Property(e => e.MapTags).HasConversion<List<int>>();

[Serializable]
public class MapInfo
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    public List<MapTag> MapTags { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

public enum MapTag
{
    Group1 = 1000,
    Group2 = 1001,
    Group3 = 1002,
}

I tried querying in many ways but still failed.
I also read https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html and array1.All(i => array2.Contains(i)) should work.
Is there anything wrong with my code or setting?

With EF Core you can use local collection only (almost) with Contains operator, like local.Contains(x.Field).  Check this answer it shows how to procude OR conditions dynamically.

I follow that post use LINQKit's PredicateBuilder but still get error could not be translated.

Show your attempt. It should be // Method 4 but with PredicateBuilder.

here is my code query = query.Where(map => map.MapTags != null); var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New(query); foreach (var tag in param.MapTags) {  predicate = predicate.Or(f => f.MapTags.Contains(tag)); } query = query.Where(predicate);

Does simple query query.Where(map => map.MapTags.Contains(MapTag.Group1)).ToList() is translatable?

I use  dbContext.MapInfo.AsNoTracking().Where(map.MapTags.Contains(MapTag.Group1)).ToList(); to try query, but still can't translated.

I don't know, maybe it do not like enums. If simple query do not work - you cannot do anything.

I found my old code is use method 4, it's can work on my old branch. So I check its framework version , finally it's only can work on EF CORE 8.0.1.

Update
I found model setting is wrong.
The correct setting List way is
modelBuilder.Entity<MapInfo>(info =>
{
    info.PrimitiveCollection(c => c.MapTags).ElementType(e => e.HasConversion(typeof(EnumToNumberConverter<MapTag, int>)));
});


Finally, it is caused by the framework version problem.
It works when I use EF CORE 8.0.1.
But it can no longer be used after upgrading to 8.0.4.
I'm not sure if it's an EFCORE issue or an Npgsql issue.
I will post questions for them.
